# Make Floating Action Buttons scrolling in Ionic 2 app

Tags: css, ionic2

I'm trying to adjust FABs in Ionic to make them scrolling with my content. If we refer to the Ionic Exemple :

```
<ion-fab top right edge>
<button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
<ion-fab-list>
  <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
  <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
  <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

The result is the following : [image]

I'd like to make this FAB scroll with the content. I tried to overrider Ionic CSS, but when I change the position attribute it makes my button disappear..

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the case here is not css. Ionic adds the FAB button to the `fixed-content` class, so even knowing you can use css to manipulate both the fab and the fixed-content it does't scroll along with the `scroll-content` (i've tried here to find a solution for you).

Manipulating the DOM maybe works, taking out the fab from fixed-content and placing it in scroll-content with `ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer` from `@angular/core` (haven't tried this yet).

Along with manipulating the DOM, the other solution is creating your own FAB button, it can be a hard work, but there must be some examples around the internet.

Hope this helps.